# C#: Custom Colors class accessible to all projects in solution

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

I have a list of custom colors that I use in all the UI elements of my solution (which contains multiple projects). I could create a static class in one of the projects wherein I can give custom names to my colors and then access them at various points but is there a better solution for multiple projects?

```
static class MyColors
{
   public static myColor1 = Color.FromArgb(239, 247, 172);
   .
   .
   . 
}
```

Would it also be possible to view these custom colors in the property grid of the controls? For example, most of my backgrounds have a single custom color and instead of copying RGB values, I would like to be able to select my custom color. I understand I can code it in programmatically using MyColors class but it would be nice if there is a way to add it to the properties grid.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your intention to "skin" your application? I.e. provide run-time theming? In other words, should your color properties represent selected colors that you want to offer to a user, or should a color property represent the current color of a certain element? To add a specific list of color to the Visual Studio's property grid to be available for any control's Color property is not possible, since `PropertyGrid` uses the metadata stored in the active control to decide how to display each property.

Comment: That isn't my intention at this stage, I would just like to be consistent in my colors assigned in different user controls. It's fine when I use one of the preset colors as then I can just background = white but my situation is more like background = myColor1

Comment: No i do not want to offer them to a user.

Comment: The UITypeEditor for the Color struct is fixed with an [Editor] attribute, selecting System.Drawing.Design.ColorEditor.  Replacing all the controls with a derived version that has a custom TypeConverter so you could use another UITypeEditor is very unpractical.

Comment: I don't want to replace anything; simply, I just want a single 'location' to store all my custom colors and have easy access to it. I am just wondering what the best method to do this is, if not a global static class.

Comment: @Groo I just read your comment edit. So then a static class is my best option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I was about to post a long answer about how this is not possible, but then after some research I figured out what you are trying to do!

Firstly, using a static class to store your colors is a common and acceptable way to store your common colors.  You can continue using that approach.

Here's what you need to do to expose these colors in the designer:

1. Create a `CustomColors` class that encapsulates your custom colors.
2. Create a `TypeConverter` that can convert between a `string` and `CustomColor`
3. Create an `IExtenderProvider` that adds a `CustomForeColor` and `CustomBackColor` to all of the controls on your form.
4. Anywhere you want to use your custom colors, you just need to add your extender provider to your form (it will appear in the toolbox after you compile), and then CustomForeColor and CustomBackColor will appear as virtual properties for all controls, with a nice drop down.

Here's the end result:

[image]

The sky's the limit and if you want, you can create a custom UITypeEditor to actually paint the color in the propertygrid, but that's probably not necessary since you can inspect the ForeColor and BackColor properties.
Lots of helpful information on how to do this was found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

And here's the code:

**CustomColor.cs**

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(CustomColorTypeConverter))]
public class CustomColor
{
    public static CustomColor Stop = new CustomColor { Color = Color.Red };
    public static CustomColor Go = new CustomColor { Color = Color.Green };
    public static CustomColor Yield = new CustomColor { Color = Color.Yellow };

    public Color Color { get; private set; }

    internal static CustomColor Find(Color color)
    {
        if (color == CustomColor.Stop.Color)
            return CustomColor.Stop;
        else if (color == CustomColor.Go.Color)
            return CustomColor.Go;
        else if (color == CustomColor.Yield.Color)
            return CustomColor.Yield;

        return new CustomColor { Color = Color.Transparent };
    }
}
```

**CustomColorTypeConverter.cs**

```
public class CustomColorTypeConverter : StringConverter
{
    static Dictionary<CustomColor, string> _nameIndex = InitializeNameIndex();
    static Dictionary<string, CustomColor> _colorIndex = InitializeColorIndex();

    private static Dictionary<string, CustomColor> InitializeColorIndex()
    {
        return typeof(CustomColor)
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => (CustomColor)f.GetValue(null));
    }

    private static Dictionary<CustomColor, string> InitializeNameIndex()
    {
        return typeof(CustomColor)
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .ToDictionary(f => (CustomColor)f.GetValue(null), f => f.Name);
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return new System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection(_nameIndex.Values.ToList());
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(CustomColor))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            CustomColor result;
            if (_colorIndex.TryGetValue((string)value, out result))
                return result;
            else
                return new CustomColor();
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string) && value is CustomColor)
        {
            string result;
            if (_nameIndex.TryGetValue((CustomColor)value, out result))
                return result;
            else
                return String.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomColorExtenderProvider.cs**

```
[ProvideProperty("CustomForeColor", typeof(Control))]
[ProvideProperty("CustomBackColor", typeof(Control))]
public class CustomColorExtenderProvider : Component, IExtenderProvider
{
    public CustomColor GetCustomForeColor(Control control)
    {
        return CustomColor.Find(control.ForeColor);
    }

    public CustomColor GetCustomBackColor(Control control)
    {
        return CustomColor.Find(control.BackColor);
    }

    public void SetCustomBackColor(Control control, CustomColor value)
    {
        control.BackColor = value.Color;
    }

    public void SetCustomForeColor(Control control, CustomColor value)
    {
        control.ForeColor = value.Color;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeCustomForeColor(Control control)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeCustomBackColor(Control control)
    {
        return false;
    }

    #region IExtenderProvider Members

    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        return (extendee is Control);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Nice effort.  Of course, the next question is going to be about displaying the color in the PropertyGrid and in the drop down.  See [UITypeEditor Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: @LarsTech Good point.  I did mention this in my post; the OP will need to implement GetPaintValueSupported and PaintValue to acheive this functionality.  Depending on the depth of the project, looking at the corresponding ForeColor and BackColor properties may be suitable without having to create a custom UITypeEditor, depending on the number of custom colors being exposed.

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much! That was a huge effort on your part. I really appreciate it!

Comment: My pleasure, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I make it quite simply: a static class is defined, e.g.

```
public static class GraphicalProperties
{
    public static readonly Color    ControlBackColor    = Color.FromArgb(128, 32, 48);
    public static readonly Color    ControlForeColor    = Color.White;
    public static readonly Font     ControlFont         = new Font("Consolas", 10);
}
```

Then, in the constructor of each control you simply add

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BackColor   = GraphicalProperties.ControlBackColor;
    ForeColor   = GraphicalProperties.ControlForeColor;
    Font        = GraphicalProperties.ControlFont;
}
```

This provides little automatism and no entries in the Property Grid, but very simple and, in my view, practicable.